# PHP file in <img> tag cannot be referenced using query string

Tags: php, mysql, gd

i m trying to display an image stored in a database by passing the `image_id(an auto increment field)` into the query string and then including `imagedisplay.php(file used to display the image)` in image tag.  The problem is that this file, `imagedisplay.php` is not access ie the control never seems to go into the file. The code for both the main file and the `imagedisplay.php` file are below. Please note that i m not able to write the head part of the code here due to some formatting issue. The head section is standard html section pre-formatted in Dreamweaver.

```
<body>
<div class="page shadow-round">


<div id="header">
<div id="logo">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/header.js"></script>
</div>
</div>
<div id="menu">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/navmenu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
</div>


<div class="content overflow" style="height:900px;">

<?php
require_once 'login.php';  //contains the classes for connecting to databases
$dbh=new DB_Mysql;         //executing queries  
$func=new DB_Mysql_code_functions;

session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    echo<<<_END
    <form method="post" action="admin_social_activities.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table width="990">
    <tbody>
    <tr><td>Select an image file to be uploaded:</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" value="UPLOAD" /></td></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </form>
_END;

    if(isset($_FILES['imagefile']['tmp_name']))
    {   
        $imagefile=$_FILES['imagefile']['tmp_name'];
        $image_size=$_FILES['imagefile']['size'];
        $image_name=addslashes($_FILES['imagefile']['name']);
        $image_data = addslashes(file_get_contents($imagefile));

        $image_array=getimagesize($imagefile);
        $image_type=$image_array['mime'];
        $image_height=$image_array[1];
        $image_width=$image_array[0];

        $maxfilesize=2000000;

        if($maxfilesize<$image_size)
        {
            echo "Please upload a smaller image. The size of the image is too   large.";
        }
        else
        {

            $query="INSERT INTO gallery(image_name,image_type,image,image_size)  VALUES ('".    $image_name."','".$image_type."','".$image_data."','".$image_size."')";
            $stmt=$dbh->execute($query);
            $lastimageid=mysql_insert_id();
        echo "<p>You uploaded this image</p>";
        echo "<img src='imagedisplay.php?imageid=".$lastimageid."' />";
        }
    }
}
else

echo "<br/><br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Your are <span class=\"red\"><b>not   Authorized</b></span> to view this page. If you are the Admin, please login with your   credentials again. <a href='login_page.php'>Click here to continue</a>";


?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the problem is that the control never goes to `imagedisplay.php` ie. it fails to reference `imagedisplay.php` altogether.

the code for `imagedisplay.php` is below:

```
<?php
require_once 'login.php';
$dbh= new DB_Mysql();
$func=new DB_Mysql_code_functions;
$id=$_GET['imageid'];
$query="SELECT * FROM gallery where image_id=".$id;

$stmt=$dbh->execute($query);
$row=$stmt->fetch_row();
$imagedata=$row[3];
header("Content-type:image/jpeg");
echo $imagedata;
?>
```

I have tried all permutation combinations with the quotes, tried echo statements to see if control enters the file....but it does not...it stays in the main file only...i dont understand the reason...please help...please don't worry about SQL injections as i plan to deal with them later, once the code starts working....thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your echo command should be like this:

```
echo '<img src="imagedisplay.php?imageid=' . $lastimageid . ' " />';
```

Look at your generated HTML source and make sure it's right. Check your error log to see if you are getting any errors from your image script.

Comment: I put an extra space at the end to make it easier to read the apostrophe quote after the second concat.

Comment: I tried what u suggested..it does not seem to work :(...also the html source shows the correct format and the php error log do not show any errors....i don't know whats going wrong here!

Comment: New problem, i checked the html source and its path is fine....i used FireBug to trace the problem, it shows the "Image corrupt or truncated" but while uploading the file, it does not show any errors. Also when i write the same data into a new file eg new.jpg, the image file turns out to be fine. Any clues what is happening here...

Comment: I checked one of my scripts I used a long time ago where I was echoing an image from file_get_contents and it worked, so your method should work too. Maybe as a test you could fwrite the data from the db to a temp file, then file_get_contents that file and echo the results.